# crystal reports formula for: null safe equals

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-xi

The problem in the following formula is that `isnull` does not accept a variable (like o1 or o2), instead is requires a field (like the database column ACCEPTED).

```
StringVar o1:={SF_POs.ACCEPTED__C_};
StringVar o2:={RPL_POs.ACCEPTED};
if isnull(o1) then isnull(o2) // error: isnull argument requires a field
else if isnull(o2) then isnull(o1)
else o1=o2
```

I need this to return true when both fields are null or when the strings are equal.  Can someone please provide a work around?

Comment: Why store the values in stringvars? Can you just reference them directly? i.e. `isnull({SF_POs.ACCEPTED__C_})`

Comment: In one case I'm comparing a date and a string.  Unusual I know, but there is a good reason to do that.  I see your point now, I should update my example tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

you can call the fields like this, hope this works.

```
StringVar o1:={SF_POs.ACCEPTED__C_};
StringVar o2:={RPL_POs.ACCEPTED}; 
if(totext({SF_POs.ACCEPTED__C_}) == '' ) then 
(
   o2 := null;
)
else
(
o2:={RPL_POs.ACCEPTED}
)
if(totext({RPL_POs.ACCEPTED}) = '') then
(
    o1 :=null;<br>
)
else
(
)
```

something like this may help, tc

Comment: Under Report, Options, there is a feature to 'Convert Database NULL Values to Default' that does something like what your doing above.  The goal is to use null values as-is (not use a feature or code like this).  There can be a difference between an empty string and null.  I had to stop storing them in variables and reference them directly as suggested above.